# Что такое версия в IndexedDB?

Tags: javascript, база-данных, nosql, indexeddb

Начал изучать indexedDB по книжкам 12-го года и что то не чего не работает, начал мониторить в поисковике и понял что добавилось новое событие которое проверяет номер версии и только после данной проверки, можно работать с базой, но при этом что такое версия и какова цель установления версии и почему она так важна не где не говорится, может ли кто разъяснить эти вопросы?